# Usage of functions with joins

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to select a value based on something I extract from it, and the query doesn't seem to work.

Here it is:

```
SELECT meta_key 
from tbl 
    JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.name=SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(meta_key, '"', 4), '"', -1)
```

It just returns `tbl`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give some example data of `tbl.meta_key` and `tbl2.name`?

Comment: You only seem to be selecting a field from `tbl` what were you expecting. As Marco said, table definitions, sample data and expected output are needed

Answer (score 1):

You're returning the column `meta_key` which is what's on your SELECT clause. If you want some column from tbl2, add it to the select clause. For instance:

```
 SELECT meta_key, tbl2.*
   FROM ...
```

As a side note: Your meta_key looks like the combination of several "sub_keys", in the form `sub_key1"sub_key2"sub_key3"sub_key4"sub_key5`. This is not a recommended practice from the point of view of relational theory. It would be easier to have separate columns for the different sub_key. You can have a primary key which is actually composite keys. See, for instance, [How to properly create composite primary keys - MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835978/how-to-properly-create-composite-primary-keys-mysql). Doing it this way, your WHERE clause becomes straightforward:  `WHERE tbl2.name = sub_keyX` and you could have an index on `sub_keyX` to optimize access.